# Google map api number of limit of markers Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Like from my previous question, I'm currently making an android application that includes google map api. as I noticed, only 20 markers are only displayed on my app when I called "restaurants". Can anybody tell me if there's a limit of number of markers in android with the free google map api?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: using clusters not an option?

Comment: What i'm asking is if there is a limit to how many markers displayed on Android google map api? I have already read about clustering. My concern though is that on my app, it won't show more than 20 markers anymore. So I'm asking if there's some kind of limit.